# XeLaTeX - Issue with Devanagari header

Tags: fonts, xetex, header-footer, indic, mapping

I'm currently working on a project wherein I'm using RomDev mapping technique to print Devanagari characters using Roman transliteration through XeLaTeX.

The Minimum Working Example is as follows:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setmainfont{Lato}
\newfontfamily\fc{Lohit Devanagari}[Mapping=RomDev,Script=Devanagari]
\newfontfamily\fsh{Lohit Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{\fc{arjuna viṣāda yoga} -- Arjuna viṣāda yoga}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textbar{}\textbar{} 1.1 \textbar{}\textbar{}}
    
\fc{
\textit{dhṛtarāṣṭra uvāca}

dharmakṣetre kurukṣetre samavetā yuyutsavaḥ |

māmakāḥ pāṇḍavāścaiva kimakurvata sañjaya}
\end{center}
    
\begin{center}

\textit{dhṛtarāṣṭra uvāca}

dharma-kṣetre kuru-kṣetre 

samavetā yuyutsavaḥ

māmakāḥ pāṇḍavāś caiva

kim akurvata sañjaya
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\textbf{    \textbar{}\textbar{} 1.2 \textbar{}\textbar{}}

 \fc{\textit{sañjaya uvāca}
    
    dṛṣṭvā tu pāṇḍavānīkaṃ  vyūḍhaṃ duryodhanastadā | \textbar{}
    
    ācāryamupasaṅgamya          rājā vacanamabravīt}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
 
\textit{sañjaya uvāca}

dṛṣṭvā tu pāṇḍavānīkaṁ

vyūḍhaṁ duryodhanas tadā

ācāryam upasaṅgamya

rājā vacanam abravīt
\end{center}



\begin{center}
\textbf{\textbar{}\textbar{} 1.3 \textbar{}\textbar{}}
\\ \fc{paśyaitāṃ pāṇḍuputrāṇāmācārya mahatīṃ camūm 

vyūḍhāṃ drupadaputreṇa  tava śiṣyeṇa dhīmatā}

\end{center}
\begin{center}
paśyaitāṁ pāṇḍu-putrāṇām

ācārya mahatīṁ camūm

vyūḍhāṁ drupada-putreṇa

tava śiṣyeṇa dhīmatā
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\textbf{    \textbar{}\textbar{} 1.4 \textbar{}\textbar{}}
\\ \fc{atra śūrā maheṣvāsā  bhīmārjunasamā yudhi
    
    yuyudhāno virāṭaśca     drupadaś ca mahārathaḥ

}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    atra śūrā maheṣvāsā
    
    bhīmārjuna-samā yudhi
    
    yuyudhāno virāṭaś ca
    
    drupadaś ca mahā-rathaḥ
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{    \textbar{}\textbar{} 1.5 \textbar{}\textbar{}}
    \\ 
\fc{dhṛṣṭaketuścekitānaḥ kāśirājaśca vīryavān 
    
    purujit kuntibhojaśca śaibyaśca narapuṅgavaḥ}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    
    dhṛṣṭaketuś cekitānaḥ
    
    kāśirājaś ca vīryavān
    
    purujit kuntibhojaś ca
    
    śaibyaś ca nara-puṅgavaḥ
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{    \textbar{}\textbar{} 1.6 \textbar{}\textbar{}}
    \\ 
\fc{yudhāmanyuśca vikrānta uttamaujāśca vīryavān

saubhadro draupadeyāśca sarva eva mahārathāḥ}
\end{center}
\begin{center}

yudhāmanyuś ca vikrānta

uttamaujāś ca vīryavān

saubhadro draupadeyāś ca

 sarva eva mahā-rathāḥ
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\textbf{    \textbar{}\textbar{} 1.7 \textbar{}\textbar{}}
\\ \fc{asmākaṃ tu viśiṣṭā ye tānnibodha dvijottama
    
    nāyakā mama sainyasya   saṃjñārthaṃ tānbravīmi te}\\
\end{center}
\begin{center}
asmākaṁ tu viśiṣṭā ye

tān nibodha dvijottama

nāyakā mama sainyasya

saṁjñārthaṁ tān bravīmi te
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

I've shared a link with the screenshot of the exact issue. It shows how the header is jumbled up. Also one can see how we are able to generate both the Roman transliteration and the Devanagari script quite flawlessly.

[image: screenshot of a messed up header]

**My questions are:**

1. Why are the Devanagari characters in the header getting messed up? How can it be rectified?
2. Can I make the header to not get formatted in Italics+CAPS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. (1) I cannot get your tex file to compile: the WE in MWE = working example - it looks like it is a chapter to be included in some other file. (2) It is not really minimal, the M in MWE (900 lines of code can be shrunk down to, say, a handful of lines. (3) There is no tec file (4) The map file is not there either - likely it will have the answer (e.g. R is not mapped) (5) Please post code here (edit your question) as links will break over time and any answer will not have the context for understanding. (6) Why are you typing in Latin capitals?

Comment: If you can use another input method to save your file as mixed Latin/Devanagari in UTF-8, you might have fewer problems.

Comment: Thanks @Davislor! I got this advise from another experienced gentleman also.

Comment: @Cicada : I've posted the code based on your comments.

Comment: @Davislor I tried your suggestion. But I'm having some issues with it. I've posted my problem as a separate question
(https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587753/xelatex-issue-with-devanagari-header-contd).

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amended answer:

With the MWE code as supplied in the comments, it is clearer what is going on.

By fortunate coincidence, the `fancyhdr` package, which allows customisation of headers and footers, explains in the documentation, amongst other things, that the default page style applies `\textsl` (slanted text) and `\MakeUppercase` to the page headers.

Mapping in xelatex takes place as the very last step, in this case after the `\MakeUppercase` command was applied to the chapter heading.

It was `\MakeUppercase` that was converting `r` to `R` and so on, and the mapping file was not set up to define what glyph(s) input `R` should be mapped to, so it wasn't, and appeared in the output as itself. Similarly for the other unmapped characters. Mapped characters, like `A`, were converted to Deva OK.

`fancyhdr` package gives some tutorial examples of the effects of making changes to the commands used by TeX's marking mechanism.

One of the examples is:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
```

which works suitably for us as one solution in this case, and we use it to produce this:

[image: chapterheader]

MWE

```
%compile with xelatex for mapping to take effect
\documentclass{book} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\usepackage{fontspec, lipsum}   
\newfontfamily\fc{Lohit Devanagari}[Mapping=RomDev,Script=Devanagari]  
\newfontfamily\fsh{Lohit Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]   
%========================================  
 \begin{document}   
 \chapter{sample-{\fc bhāratam}-{\fsh भारतम्}}   
 \lipsum[1-25]   
 \end{document}
```

---

Original answer:

Using the `.map` file from here from 11 years ago:
https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev
and compiling to `.tec` binary using teckit_compile:

(1) To obtain Devanagari characters via the RomDev mapping, type using the Latin characters that are in the RomDev mapping.

[image: romdev1]

`R` is not mapped.

[image: romdev2]

`R`+vowel is mapped, and `r`+consonant is mapped and so on, but not `R`+consonant.

(2) The solution to the header question will depend on the packages and code being used. Please supply a small but working example so people can see such and then test their answers against.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\fc{Shobhika}[Mapping=RomDev,Script=Devanagari]
\newfontfamily\fsh{Shobhika}[Script=Devanagari]
%========================================
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
{\fc arjun} & \fc Arjun & \fc ARJUN \\
arjun & Arjun & ARJUN \\
\end{tabular}

\section{{\fc arjun} Arjun}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
Map from & Map to \\
a            & \fc a   \\
r            & \fc r  \\
R            & \fc R\\
ro            & \fc ro  \\
Ro            & \fc Ro\\
rj            & \fc rj  \\
Rj            & \fc Rj\\
Ṛ            & \fc Ṛ\\
Ṝ             & \fc Ṝ\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cicada. You have answered my first question partially.  _Why are the Devanagari characters getting messed up? How can it be rectified?_  Can I manually change the .map file to rectify the problem?  Can you please answer my second question also?

Comment: There is not enough information to be able to answer the second question. For the header formatting to answer your second question, people will need to see a (small but compilable) MWE, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Formatting is done via the class and packages being used, and the answer will depend on which ones are in play. I cannot guess what code you have called, and I could not find any such in the external links, just a chapter file (which does not compile, of course). Post your MWE here.

Comment: To rectify the `Devanagari characters getting messed up`, the easiest way is to use only RomDev mapped-latin letters, in my example like so:  `\section{{\fc arjun} Arjun}`. But direct input, with no mapping needed, is better: अर्जुन.

Comment: It may be that you are typing RomDev mapped letters, but the class or a package or a setting does uppercase on section headings.

Comment: Thanks @Cicada for your nice explanation. Please excuse my delayed response. Please find the MWE regarding my second question as follows:  <br/>

```\documentclass[draft]{book} 

\usepackage{fontspec, lipsum} 

\newfontfamily\fc{Lohit Devanagari}[Mapping=RomDev,Script=Devanagari]

\newfontfamily\fsh{Lohit Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari] 

%======================================== 

\begin{document} 

\chapter{sample-{\fc bhāratam}-{\fsh भारतम्}} 

\lipsum[1-5] 

\end{document}```

Comment: This is the chapter header. 

[https://imgur.com/Oj7e8CM.png](https://imgur.com/Oj7e8CM.png)

The following is the Chapter title.
[https://imgur.com/Pip12aX.png](https://imgur.com/Pip12aX.png)

Comment: Now I understand: The default page style uses `\textsl` (slanted text) and `\MakeUppercase`. See `fancyhdr` package (do `texdoc fancyhdr`) to see how and why, and how to modify the page headers. Unrelated: you can edit your question and post the code in there. I don't have time tonight to do an example. Apologies.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}`. It still comes out italic for the Latin letters, but Deva is OK. It was the MakeUppercase that was converting r->R etc.

Comment: Thank you so much @Cicada! I've marked your answer as the solution. Can you please edit your answer which includes our discussion in the comments as well? So that anyone who searches for a similar problem can find it easier.  Also where can I get started to learn the intricacies of LaTeX such as the one you've mentioned in your last comment? That will help me to understand LaTeX better and have more control over the final output

Comment: See amended answer. As to learning resources, browse this site for exactly that question to get many useful responses. Search in general on the internet for "Short Guide to Latex" or variations thereof (brief, introduction) to get results from different people, institutions and libraries. Also, the Latex Wikibooks are quite useful and friendly. And reading some of the package descriptions on the CTAN site will give an idea of what is available in terms of specialties and customisations.