# XeLaTeX - Issue with Devanagari header (contd.)

Tags: xetex, indic

This question is in continuation with [my earlier question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576852/xelatex-issue-with-devanagari-header)
I am not sure whether this fits in my previous question. Therefore, I am asking a new question.

The MWE is as follows:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily{\pst}[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter[\pst{अर्जुन विषाद योग} -- Arjuna viṣāda yoga]{\pst{अर्जुन विषाद योग} \\ Arjuna viṣāda yoga}
%\chapter[Arjuna viṣāda yoga -- \pst{अर्जुन विषाद योग}]{Arjuna viṣāda yoga \\ \pst{अर्जुन विषाद योग}}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

**Screenshot of the chapter title:**
[image]

**Screenshot of the header:**
[image]

When the the argument of `chapter` command in the MWE is slightly modified to have the Latin characters in the first line followed by the Devanagari characters, everything is alright (as shown below).

**Screenshot of the modified title:**
[image]

**Screenshot of the modified header:**
[image]

But I want the Devanagari to be followed by the Latin Characters both in the chapter title and the header.

How can this be achieved? Can someone help me out?

Comment: \pst is a font switch. It doesn't take an argument. Move the brace before the command:  `{\pst अर्जुन विषाद योग}`

Comment: Another tip for multi-lingual documents: add `\tracinglostchars=2` near the top of your preamble. You’ll get a warning message when the current font is missing a glyph you requested (which usually means you selected a different language than you’re typing in).

Comment: You could also use `onchar=ids fonts` with `babel` in LuaLaTeX, or `ucharclasses` in XeLaTeX, to automatically detect the language you’re typing in and select the correct font family.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks!! Such a simple yet serious misktake. Thanks again!

Comment: @Davislor I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ulrike Fischer's comment is the answer.

> `\pst` is a font switch.  It doesn't take an argument. Move the brace before the command: `{\pst अर्जुन विषाद योग}`